# Responsive image with a fallback background color of the same dimensions

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

In my application, a list of items each has a square 108x108px image associated with it. I am trying to display the images responsively, but if there is no image url in the database, I want to show a backup grey square with the same dimensions as the image would have.

By default, when the user loads the page, the grey squares will be presented, but when the user loads data into the `src=""` attribute of the `<img>` via jQuery, it should exactly cover up the grey square. I have been attempting to use a CSS `background: #ddd` on the `<img>` tag to some success, but I cannot get the background to display with the same dimensions that the image would use if it were loaded. Given that I know the exact dimensions, this seems easy until you get to smaller screen widths, and the image (or background) would need to shrink to fit the containing `<div>` without getting cropped.

Basically, I have a container div with a percentage-based width. When that width becomes <108px, the `<img>` should have `width:100%` and `height:auto`, and the grey background should match those same dimensions.

Comment: try something like this: `var resizeBG = function() {
                var hh = $('image').height();
                var ww = $('image').width();
                $('containerDiv').css({ 'height':hh, 'width':ww });
            };`
            `$('img').load(function() {
                resizeBG();
            });`

            `$(window).resize(function() {
                resizeBG();
            });`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Patrick. Your jQuery solution works well in sizing the images and the grey placeholders down when it has an image loaded to reference. Unfortunately, the function doesn't work when increasing the size, and no grey placeholders are shown when none of the images are loaded in yet.

Comment: Show us some HTML and your CSS.